# Applying OOPs Pattern in React Functional Compoenent

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. And in react functional component, I want to create reusable and flexible common component. Prior react I saw generally we try to avoid any tightly couple logic in component directly, Example: For a Save button click say I have written logic to, validate => show error => if error, return => if no error => proceed, inside its component directly. Say some other developer don't want this behavior at all they have their own logic they want to perform and override the method of Save click. So I just wanted to know what is the general approach experts suggests in these cases, given I don't want common component code to get touched a lot as well, yet overriding should be allowed.
I am using smart and dumb component approach a-lot to give user flexibility of writing their own logic and additionally per component I have made a class for it with default logic defined in class, and component expecting the instance of class or extended class (with user defined overridden function) from smart component, is this valid design pattern approach of writing code in react functional component? Example:
// Utility class (Smart Logic)

```
export default class ComponentState {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      loading: false,
      error: null,
    };
    this.url = ""; // Default URL
    this.listeners = new Set();
  }

  setUrl = (newUrl) => {
    this.url = newUrl;
  };

  subscribe = (listener) => {
    this.listeners.add(listener);
  };

  unsubscribe = (listener) => {
    this.listeners.delete(listener);
  };

  notify = () => {
    this.listeners.forEach((listener) => listener(this.state));
  };

  setState = (newState) => {
    this.state = { ...this.state, ...newState };
    this.notify();
  };
  //Define the method as an arrow function: If you define your method as an arrow function in the class property, it will automatically be bound to the instance.
  fetchData = () => {
    if (!this.url) return; // Ensure URL is set before fetching
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(this.url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ data, loading: false }))
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ error, loading: false }));
  };
}
```

```
// Dumb Component (Presentational)
const MyComponent = ({ componentState, fetchData }) => {
  console.log(componentState);
  return (
    <div>
      {componentState.loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {componentState.data && <pre>{componentState.data.title}</pre>}
      {componentState.error && <p>Error: {componentState.error}</p>}
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Fetch Data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ComponentState from "../utils/ComponentState";
import MyComponent from "./DumbComponent";

// Smart Component (Container)
const SmartComponent = () => {
  // Instance of the utility class
  //In this version, useRef is used to create a persistent reference to the ComponentState instance, which ensures that the same instance is used throughout the component’s lifecycle. This should help maintain the correct this context within the fetchData method.
  const stateManager = useRef(new ComponentState()).current;

  // Use a state hook to force re-render
  const [, forceUpdate] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (newState) => {
      forceUpdate(newState);
    };

    stateManager.subscribe(listener);
    // Set the URL for fetching data
    stateManager.setUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    console.log(stateManager);

    return () => {
      stateManager.unsubscribe(listener);
    };
  }, [stateManager]);

  return (
    <MyComponent
      componentState={stateManager.state}
      fetchData={stateManager.fetchData}
    />
  );
};

export default SmartComponent;
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SmartComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s a general answer to this; a lot will come down to opinions and requirements.

Comment: But @DaveNewton will this approach fail, in large code base or will introduce some anti pattern that will be complex to handle when we want scale?

Comment: You already exhibit an antipattern with the requirement to have a `forceUpdate` state atom. For your example, a data loader, use one of the hooks meant for that, e.g. [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) or react-query.

Comment: @AKX what do you suggest then , should I make handlers with default definition and and write logic to in component like: if present in prop use that else use default? And the component has so many events based items like input and buttons

Comment: Nothing in your example shows a component that would have inputs or buttons, and there's no generic silver bullet solution.

Comment: thats a generic example the actual dumb component has 5 input fields and 3 buttons, each associated with independent logic to handle.

Comment: And that makes all the difference. A form-style component with 5 input fields and 3 buttons is nothing like a component that's supposed to just load data from a remote source.